# How do bson arrays compare (in mongodb/pymongo)?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bson

I would like to store in mongdb some very large integers, exactly (several thousands decimal digits). This will not work of course with the standard types supported by BSON, and I am trying to think of the most elegant workaround, considering that I would like to perform range searches and similar things. This requirement excludes storing the integers as strings as it makes the range searches impractical.

One way I can think of is to encode the 2^32-expansion using (variable-length) arrays of standard ints, and add to this array a first entry for the length of the array itself. That way lexicographical ordering on these arrays corresponds to the usual ordering of arbitrarily large integers.

For instance, in a collection I could have the 5 documents

```
{"name": "me", "fortune": [1,1000]}
{"name": "scrooge mcduck", "fortune": [11,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
{"name": "bruce wayne","fortune": [2, 10,0]}
{"name": "bill gates", "fortune": [2,1,1000]}
{"name": "francis", "fortune": [0]}
```

Thus Bruce Wayne's net worth is 10*2^32, Bill Gates' 2^32+1000 and Scrooge McDuck's 2^320.

I can then do a sort using {"fortune":1} and on my machine (with pymongo) it returns them in the order francis < me < bill < bruce < scrooge, as expected.

However, I am making assumptions that I haven't seen documented anywhere about the way BSON arrays compare, and the range searches don't seem to work  the way I think (for instance,

```
find({"fortune":{$gte:[2,5,0]}})
```

returns no document, but I would wish for bruce and scrooge).

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Both the solutions described below by Dhruv and Remon require that I know the maximal length, and that I store lots of padding zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead store left padded strings which represent exact integer equal to the fortune.

```
eg.  "1000000" = 1 million
     "0010000" = 10 thousand
     "2000000" = 2 million
     "0200000" = 2 hundred thousand
```

Left padding with zeroes will ensure that lexographical comparison of these strings directly corresponds to their comparison as numeric values also. You will have to
assume a safe MAXIMUM possible value of fortune here, say a 20 digit number, and
pad the 0s accordingly
So a sample documents would be :

```
  {"name": "scrooge mcduck", "fortune": "00001100000000000000" }
  {"name": "bruce wayne",    "fortune": "00000200000000000000" }
```

querying:

```
> db.test123.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e142f1573cffecd0f65e"), "name" : "bruce wayne", "fortune" : "00000200000000000000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e150f1573cffecd0f65f"), "name" : "donald", "fortune" : "00000150000000000000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e160f1573cffecd0f660"), "name" : "mickey", "fortune" : "00000000000000100000" }


> db.test123.find({ "fortune" : {$gte: "00000200000000000000"}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e142f1573cffecd0f65e"), "name" : "bruce wayne", "fortune" : "00000200000000000000" }


> db.test123.find({ "fortune" : {$lt: "00000200000000000000"}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e150f1573cffecd0f65f"), "name" : "donald", "fortune" : "00000150000000000000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f87e160f1573cffecd0f660"), "name" : "mickey", "fortune" : "00000000000000100000" }
```

The querying / sorting will work naturally as mongodb compares strings lexographically.
However, to do other numeric operations on your data, you will have to write custom logic in your data processing script ( PHP,Python,Ruby etc)

For querying and data storage, this string version should do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your assumption about array comparison is incorrect. Range queries that, for example, query for all array values smaller than 3 ({array:{$lt:3}}) will return all arrays where at least one element is less than three, regardless of the element's position. As such your approach will not work.

What does work, but is a bit less obvious, is using binary blobs for your very large integers since those are byte-order compared. That requires you set an upper bit limit for your integers but that should be fairly straightforward. You can test it in shell using BinData(subType, base64) notation :

```
db.col.find({fortune:{$gt:BinData(0, "e8MEnzZoFyMmD7WSHdNrFJyEk8M=")}})
```

So all you'd have to do is create methods to convert your big integers from, say, strings to two-complements binary and you're set. Good luck